# Android Material Design profile page

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm new to android and material design. Could some one please help me point to any websites that help me build a profile screen as below as per Google's material design guidelines?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Answer (score 97):

I was about to write a blog on this screen briefing about `CoordinatorLayout`. Anyways.. You can have my fully working code.:

[image]

**activity_scrolling.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.letsnurture.ln_202.coordinatorlayoutpart1.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="218dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/google_thumb"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_scrolling.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.letsnurture.ln_202.coordinatorlayoutpart1.ScrollingActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivContactItem1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNumber1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivContactItem1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivContactItem1"
                android:text="(123) 456-7890"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="#212121" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvNumber1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivContactItem1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivContactItem1"
                android:text="Home"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textColor="#727272" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/chkState1"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
                android:checked="true"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn="" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivContactItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_black_24dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNumber2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivContactItem2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivContactItem2"
                android:text="(321) 654-0987"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="#212121" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvNumber2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivContactItem2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivContactItem2"
                android:text="Work"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textColor="#727272" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/chkState2"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
                android:checked="false"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn="" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/item_divider" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivContactItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNumber3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivContactItem3"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chkState3"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivContactItem3"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/chkState3"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="chintan@letsnurture.com"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="#212121" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvNumber3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivContactItem3"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivContactItem3"
                android:text="Home"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textColor="#727272" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/chkState3"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
                android:checked="true"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn="" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivContactItem4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNumber4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivContactItem4"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chkState4"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivContactItem4"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/chkState4"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="pratik@letsnurture.com"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="#212121" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvNumber4"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivContactItem4"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivContactItem4"
                android:text="Work"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textColor="#727272" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/chkState4"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn="" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/item_divider" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivContactItem5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNumber5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivContactItem5"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chkState5"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivContactItem5"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/chkState5"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="202 Park Street, Los Angeles"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="#212121" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvNumber5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivContactItem5"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivContactItem5"
                android:text="Home"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textColor="#727272" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/chkState5"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
                android:checked="true"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn="" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivContactItem6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNumber6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivContactItem6"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chkState6"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivContactItem6"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/chkState6"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="221B Baker Street, England"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="#212121" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvNumber6"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivContactItem6"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivContactItem6"
                android:text="Work"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textColor="#727272" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/chkState6"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn="" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/item_divider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Send SMS" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="Call" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="Email" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="Remove Contact" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**item_divider.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#B6B6B6" />
```

**ScrollingActivity.java:**

```
public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

You can download the source from my Github repo:

https://github.com/chintansoni202/Material-Profile

Comment: What an ungrateful comment @AbAppletic, surely you know how to look at this code and figure it out for yourself!!

Comment: If what you're saying is true then he has the right to make his post link-only since "I can surely look at another answer if the link goes down!"

Comment: How to do that with recyclerview and headers? This example is pretty static

Answer (score 5):

- **Introduction** to the main principles of material design:

  http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html

---

- **Guidelines** and for developers:

  http://developer.android.com/training/material/get-started.html

---

- Really good in-depth **tutorials** on material design:

  http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/
  http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-development-tutorial-lollipop-material-design/

---

- Other needed **Resources**:

  - Icons:

    https://materialdesignicons.com/

    http://www.materialup.com/tools/icons
  - Themes

    http://materialdesignthemes.com/themes/
  - Widgets:

    http://freebiesbug.com/psd-freebies/material-design-widgets/
  - Fonts:

    https://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/roboto-noto-fonts.html

Answer (score 2):

The android developers blog is another good resource for an introduction to the components in the contacts example:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

There is no perfect tutorial but this would be a good place to start.

This tutorial that focuses on handling scrolling within coordinator layouts: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 2):

Design To achieve this take look at below xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/header"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/scrollableview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then Open your Activity.java add following code

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.anim_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Ali Connors");
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The Status Bar transparent is supported on api level 21 or higher level

```
//put below line is your style.xml.
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

create **ovel.xml** file in drawable folder and copy and past below code

```
//code start
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#f42b89"
        android:endColor="#f42b89"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
//code end
```

Write below code in your **activity_main.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    <!--android:padding="8dp"-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgProfilePic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="390dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/images" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFloating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/oval"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/right_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```