# Using CollapsingToolbarLayout, how can I set it as the support action bar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33461245/android-material-design-profile-page) tutorial, I have this `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/blurred_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/defaultimage"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
            android:id="@+id/profilePicture" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

However, I need to use `setSupportActionBar()` so I can use the `setTitle()`, `setHomeAsUpEnabled()`, etc. methods. However, apparently `CollapsingToolbarLayout` cannot be cast to `Toolbar`, and the `setSupportActionBar()` method only accepts a `Toolbar` method.

Is there a substitute method for setting it?

Comment: go through https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Why not just wrap your `ImageView`s in a `Toolbar`?

Comment: @MikeM. Nice idea, but it seems like my `ImageView`s lost the alignments they hade. (One of them was centered, now it's at the left of the screen`

Comment: In ToolBar also you can add your required child views like you do in LinearLayout , so yeah why don't you use that ?

Comment: `Toolbar` allows gravity for its children. Set `layout_gravity` as needed on the `ImageView`s.

Comment: @Tasneem Adding a `LinearLayout` did the trick

Comment: @MikeM. Please add your answer so I can accept it

Comment: Actually, if @Tasneem would like to, they can post an answer. Thanks, though. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @MikeM. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something like this :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="70dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="10dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/blurred_background"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

           <ImageView
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:adjustViewBounds="true"
              android:src="@drawable/defaultimage"
              app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
              app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
              tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
              android:id="@+id/profilePicture" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Add your image views inside LinearLayout/RelativeLayout and add Toolbar inside CollapsingToolbarLayout to achieve Toolbar functionalities.